# Bounding the differential quotient of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb C :|z| \leq 1\}$ such that $|f(z)| \leq 1.$
>
> Define $g: \mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ by
>   $$
> g(z) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{f(z)}{z} & \text{if $z\neq0$} \\
> f^{'}(0) & \text{if $z=0$}  \\
> \end{cases}.$$
>
> Then $|g(z)| \le 1\ \forall\ z \in \mathbb D$.

Is this true?

Comment: Can you appeal to the power series representation of $f$ for more insight?

Comment: @Martin: This is not a duplicate of that question. Here, $f$ is not assumed to satisfy $|f(z)| \leq |z|$.

Comment: @Michael: It isn't assumed there either and I figured the hypothesis $f(0) = 0$ was simply missing here, but you're right it's not a duplicate. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, I misread that question. I don't think you can assume that the hypothesis is missing. Maybe the question was trying to see if the Schwarz lemma was still true without that hypothesis. I also voted to reopen.

Comment: @Martin  you should see  here I've not assumed f(0)=0 ; what their assumed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right it was a mistake, sorry. Notice that the condition $f(0) = 0$ is surely necessary if you want the limit $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z}$ to exist and be equal to $f'(0)$.

Comment: @Martin Yes , I agree with you. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true. Consider the holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$, $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}$. It is certainly true that $|f(z)| \leq 1$, but $g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 2$.

The function $g$ is the one that is considered when proving the [Schwarz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), but there you have the additional requirement that $f(0) = 0$. If $f$ satisfies this condition, then $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.